# Problemas con los campos de referencia en las tablas

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo estas tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
db.define_table('marcas_definiciones',
                Field('marca', 'string', label=T('Marca GG')),
                Field('razon_zocial_gg', 'reference razones_zociales_gg'),
                Field('ruc', 'string', label=T('RUC GG')),
                format='%(marca)s')


db.define_table('cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar',
                Field('marca', 'reference marcas_definiciones'),
                Field('saldo_total_cobrar', 'float'),
                Field('saldo_total_pagar', 'float'),
                format='%(marca)s')


db.define_table('cobranzas',
                Field('marca', 'reference cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar'),
                Field('numero_comprobante', 'string'),
                Field('nota', 'text'),
                format='%(prefijo_comprobante)s %(numero_comprobante)s')
```

Este es el controlador:

```
def cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar():
    response.view = 'finances/default.html'
    form = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar, linked_tables=[
        'cobranzas',
        'pagos'
    ])
    return dict(form=form,page_name="Cuentas por cobrar")
```

Donde `cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar` tiene un campo que es de `marcas_definiciones` y la tabla `cobranzas` es una subtabla de `cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar` únicas por el campo `marca`, el problema está en que cuando quiero seleccionar la `marca` en la tabla de `cobranzas`, este aparece como numero de ID pero de la tabla `marca_definicion` y no una de las marcas de la tabla `cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estás usando una referencia para mostrar el registro, puedes intentar usando `lambda` en el [`format`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#format--Record-representation) de la tabla `cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar`:

```
db.define_table('cuentas_por_cobrar_y_pagar',
    Field('marca', 'reference marcas_definiciones'),
    Field('saldo_total_cobrar', 'float'),
    Field('saldo_total_pagar', 'float'),
    format=lambda r: r.marca.marca
)
```

Con esto aseguras la llamada al campo `marca` de la tabla `marcas_definiciones` que es un `string`.